# Erro numa Promise em JS

Tags: javascript, promises

Tenho o seguinte código:

```js
var age = parseInt(prompt('Digite sua idade: '));

function verificar(age){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        if(age > 18){
            resolve(console.log('DEU CERTO'))
        }else{
            reject(console.log('MENOR'))
        }
    })
}

verificar()
.then(
    function(){
        console.log('Maior de idade')
    }
)
.catch(
    function(){
        console.log('Menor de idade')
    }
)
```

Já converti o `prompt()` para tipo inteiro usando o `parseInt()`. O problema é que mesmo digitando uma idade maior que 18, ele continua caindo no `.catch()` e retornando que o usuário é menor de idade. Alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: Mas você não está passando parâmetro nenhum quando você invoca a função `verificar()`. Não deveria ser `verificar(age)`?

Comment: @user140828 era isso mesmo, não percebi rs. Obrigado.

Comment: alguma resposta te ajudou?

Answer (score 2):

Você esqueceu de passar "age" como parâmetro ao chamar verificar(). Por usar o mesmo nome "age" como nome de parâmetro na definição da função, o parâmetro "escondeu" a variável global.

Basta alterar a linha 13 para

```
verificar(age)
```

e provavelmente você também vai querer testar a idade usando >= em vez de >, porque 18 anos já é maior de idade.